# requirement of openess of the subset of a manifold for mayer-vietoris theorem

Tags: differential-geometry, homology-cohomology

So for a given manifold $M$ and two of $U,V$ open sets that can be used to cover $M$, one can use to mayer-vietoris theorem to relate the decomposed de rham cohomology of $M$ with that of $U$ and $V$. However, I do not see why openness is something has to be required as this is basically a consequence of snake lemma with several exact sequences.

Comment: If $U,V$ are not open it doesn't even make sense to talk of their De Rham cohomology since they are not manifolds.

Comment: Sure it does, @GeorgesElencwajg, one can do this perfectly well with manifolds with boundary, provided their interiors cover $M$. (It's just completely unnecessary, as we may pass to their interiors and thus work with open submanifolds instead.)

Comment: @Georges: I was not suggesting that arbitrary subsets are submanifolds (with boundary), simply that one could work with submanifolds that are not open submanifolds (as it seemed to me you implied). I said nothing particularly interesting :)

Comment: Dear @Mike: the status of  $U,V$ in the proposed generalization of the OP was not particularly precise. I just wanted to underline that one can't define the De Rham cohomology of an arbitrary subset of $M$. As you and Kevin suggest, submanifolds with boundaries are quite all right, I  agree.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It's not *quite* necessary that $U$ and $V$ be open. Rather, they should be submanifolds whose interiors cover $M$. (And if we work in a more general cohomology theory, we just need any subspaces whose interiors cover.) The reason for this is that we want the short exact sequence of chain complexes $C^*(U\cap V)\leftarrow C^*(U)\oplus C^*(V)\leftarrow C^*(U+V)$ (which exists regardless of $U$ and $V$) to yield a long exact sequence that's actually interesting to us, namely $H^*(U\cap V)\leftarrow H^*(U)\oplus H^*(V)\leftarrow H^*(M)$. 
**EDIT:** By $C^*(U+V)$ I mean cochains which can be decomposed into a sum of a cochain supported on $U$ and one supported on $V$. When $U$ and $V$'s interiors cover $M$, it's immediate from existence of partitions of unity that this is just $C^*(M)$, but otherwise we have no such guarantee.

But if the interiors of $U$ and $V$ don't cover $M$, there's no reason to have $C^*(U+V)$ chain homotopy equivalent to $C^*(M)$, so that we just get a lame shadow $H^*(U\cap V)\leftarrow H^*(U)\oplus H^*(V)\leftarrow H^*(U+V)$ of the long exact sequence we really want.

All of this remains a bit obscure in de Rham cohomology, because there aren't such wild coverings of manifolds by submanifolds: you can't cover a manifold with finitely many submanifolds of positive codimension. But in general this issue is quite significant. For one example, we could cover the circle with its irrational points $U$ and rational points $V$ (under a bijection with the interval) and from this deduce that $S^1$ has vanishing first cohomology!

Comment: @GeorgesElencwajg thanks for the comments. Yes to the second, but I mean something technical by $C^*(U+V)$, which I'll edit to clarify.

Comment: I have a quick follow-up dumb question. Then can one talk about de rham cohomology for an infinite dimensional manifold $M$ which can be covered only by an infinite number submanifolds say $U_1,U_2,...$? What is exact meaning of the direct sum here?

Comment: The definition of infinite dimensional manifold is not entirely straightforward, but once you have it you can define de Rham cohomology in the usual way. Your question about infinite coverings doesn't really have anything to do with this issue, as you could ask about it for infinite coverings of finite dimensional submanifolds just easily. In this case there isn't a Mayer vietoris sequence. There may be a spectral sequonce...